# How to cut holes in a rectangle (three.js)?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to cut two holes in a simple rectangle created by three.js.
My problem is that the holes are not displayed correctly (no 3d-effect).
This is my current approach:

```
const modelContainer = document.getElementById('containerModel');

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xEEEEEE);

// Camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  50,
  modelContainer.clientWidth / modelContainer.clientHeight,
  1,
  1000,
);
camera.position.set(0, 150, 400);
scene.add(camera);

// Light
const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
camera.add(light);

// Group
const group = new THREE.Group();
scene.add(group);

// Rectangle
const rectShape = new THREE.Shape()
  .moveTo(0, 0)
  .lineTo(0, 120)
  .lineTo(200, 120)
  .lineTo(200, 0)
  .lineTo(0, 0);

// Holes
const hole = new THREE.Path()
  .moveTo(144, 60)
  .absarc(134, 60, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
rectShape.holes.push(hole);
const hole2 = new THREE.Path()
  .moveTo(77, 60)
  .absarc(67, 60, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
rectShape.holes.push(hole2);

const extrudeSettings = {
  depth: 20,
  bevelEnabled: true,
  bevelSegments: 2,
  steps: 2,
  bevelSize: 1,
  bevelThickness: 1,
};
const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry(rectShape, extrudeSettings);
geometry.center();
geometry.rotateX(Math.PI * -0.5);
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x222222,
});
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
group.add(mesh);

// Renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(modelContainer.clientWidth, modelContainer.clientHeight);
new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
modelContainer.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = modelContainer.clientWidth / modelContainer.clientHeight;
  renderer.setSize(modelContainer.clientWidth, modelContainer.clientHeight);
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
```

Here is my result:
https://jsfiddle.net/9y0a64nx/27/

If i replace the rectangle with a circle shape, the holes will be displayed correctly:
https://jsfiddle.net/9y0a64nx/28/

How can i get the same 3D-effect of the holes as the circle shape?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reverse the order in which you define your outer rectangular shape:

```
const rectShape = new THREE.Shape()
    .moveTo(0, 0)
    .lineTo(rectLength, 0)
    .lineTo(rectLength, rectWidth)
    .lineTo(0, rectWidth)
    .lineTo(0, 0);
```

Keep in mind that holes muse be defined in reversed order (CW vs. CCW).

Update live example: https://jsfiddle.net/ktjqe2L4/